# Scroll a div with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a click function that slides a contact form down from the top of the page and pushes the rest of the page down. I have an absolute position DIV which stays where it is currently and I need it to scroll down as if it didn't have an absolute position.

```
$("#contact-tab").toggle(function() {
    $('#contact-form-wrapper').slideToggle();
        // scroll #absolute DIV vertically the height of #contact-form-wrapper
    }, function() {
        $('#contact-form-wrapper').slideToggle();
        // scroll #absolute back to where it was
    });

#absolute {
    position: absolute;
    top: 500px;
}
#contact-form-wrapper {
    width:100%;
    height:370px;
    top:0;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/benners/FV2sp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

consider change the position method, anyway using `progress` callback can solve the problem but you should use version 1.8+ of JQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#contact-form').hide();

    $("#contact-us").toggle(function() {
        $('#contact-form').slideToggle({
            progress:function(anime,progr,remain){
                $("#absolute").css('top',( $(this).height() + 150));
            }
        });
    }, function() {
        $('#contact-form').slideToggle({
            progress:function(anime,progr,remain){
                $("#absolute").css('top',( $(this).height() + 150));
            }
        });
    });

});
```

see updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FV2sp/2/).

Answer (score 1):

You can change the absolute positioning of the element to `position: relative`. You can get the same behaviour as `position: absolute` except that obviously, it's positioned relative to it's parent element. Check out this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/FV2sp/1/

Otherwise your other option is to place the absolutely positioned element inside your `.content` element. Then it will move as your `.content` element slides up and down.

Comment: Not doing what I was looking for really. I've added a Fiddle to the question showing what I have working. I'd like #absolute to scroll with the #contact-form

Comment: Ahh ok. The absolute positioning is a problem. Have you considered changing it's positioning to relative? That may not be what you need as you did specify an absolute position in your question, but I've provided an example of what I mean here http://jsfiddle.net/FV2sp/1/ in case it works for you. Let me know what you think.

Comment: I've hadn't been completely clear on how to use absolute and relative positioning together until I tried your suggestion and did some more reading. This is the solution I've used although it wasn't the exact answer to my question. Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use that jquery so your div follow the scroll

```
$(function() {

var $mydiv   = $(".id-of-your-div"), 
$window    = $(window),
offset     = $mydiv.offset(),
topPadding = 15;

$window.scroll(function() {
    if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
        $mydiv.stop().animate({
            marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
        });
    } else {
        $mydiv.stop().animate({
            marginTop: 0
        });
    }
});
```

});

Place it on the bottom of your page or somewhere.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not sure how I integrate this into the code I included above. Could you elaborate a little please?

Comment: Just change the .id-of-your-div with the id that you have on your div. and then place it somewhere inside your page.