# Toggle floating menu should make the content more fluid

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this Fiddle demo here, http://jsfiddle.net/fy49t/ where you can see my menu. I have a floating top menu and a floating sub menu as I want them to always be at top of the text (so they are fixed at top while I can scroll with the content/data).

The demo is working but I really would like my "content" DIV (the one with the 40 lines) to fluid follow the sub menu while it expands/shrinks (when you toggle the sub menu). The current code only makes a reposition of the content DIV *AFTER* the toggle effect has finished.

My troublesome javascript:

```
// Reposition
$(".toggleSelBox").click(function() {
  $(".toggleSelBox").toggle(400, function() {
    repositionLayout();
  });
});

// Function - move both the sub menu and content DIV below the main menu
function repositionLayout() {
  var heightMenuMain = $(".menumain").outerHeight();
  var heightMenuSub = $(".menusub").outerHeight();
  $(".menusub").css("margin-top",heightMenuMain);
  $(".content").css("margin-top",heightMenuMain+heightMenuSub);
}
```

Is it possible to get a more fluid feel of the content?

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer which revealed that I could use the `progress` function in `toggle()`, https://stackoverflow.com/a/16369563/2028935

All I need is to change this JS:

```
  $(".toggleSelBox").toggle(400, function() {
    repositionLayout();
  });
```

.. with this JS:

```
  $('.toggleSelBox').toggle({ 
    progress:function(anime,progr,remain) {
      repositionLayout();
    }
  });
```

I have updated the Fiddle demo here, http://jsfiddle.net/fy49t/1/